# Z-value in R using the Eggers test. How to get the t-value

Tags: r, meta-analysis, publication-bias

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis using R for my masterthesis. To test for publication bias I ran the Eggers test. In the output I get a z-value, however in all the published meta-analysis they report the t-value. Am I doing something wrong (if yes, what should I change) or is there any way I can transform the z to a t-value?

Comment: I don't know about Eggers test, but a t-value or a z-value usually refers to the same thing (at least in software outputs). 'z' is an estimator divided into its standard error (if you know that standard error theoretically), 't' is the same thing when the standard error is estimated. But the cases where you actually know the standard error without estimating it from data are rare ... so in practice the same thing. And one cannot simply be "transformed" to the other.

Comment: I think this question might be better directed to the r-sig-meta-analysis mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// You will need to register first and tell us which package you are using (at a guess metafor). Or you could run example(regtest) and ponder on the output.